# Can't display matches won, matches played and matches drawed by each player

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, left-join, inner-join

```
CREATE TABLE matches (
  match_id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  tournamentid INTEGER,
  player1_id INTEGER,
  player2_id INTEGER CHECK (player1_id < player2_id),
  result INTEGER CHECK (result IN (0, 1, 2)),
  FOREIGN KEY(tournamentid, player1_id) REFERENCES enroll(tournament, player_id),
  FOREIGN KEY(tournamentid, player2_id) REFERENCES enroll(tournament, player_id),
  UNIQUE(tournamentid, player1_id, player2_id)
);   

CREATE VIEW player_standings AS (
SELECT tournaments.tournament_id,
     tournaments.tournament_name,
     enroll.player_id,
     players.name,
     CASE
          WHEN matches.result = 1 THEN COUNT(matches.player1_id)
          WHEN matches.result = 2 THEN COUNT(matches.player2_id)
          END AS wins,

     COUNT(enroll.player_id IN (matches.player1_id, matches.player2_id)) AS match_played

FROM players
  INNER JOIN enroll ON enroll.player_id = players.id
  INNER JOIN tournaments ON tournaments.tournament_id = enroll.tournament
  LEFT JOIN matches ON (matches.player1_id = enroll.player_id) or
       (matches.player2_id = enroll.player_id)

GROUP BY tournaments.tournament_id, tournaments.tournament_name,   
    enroll.player_id, players.name, matches.result
ORDER BY tournaments.tournament_id, wins DESC
);
```

I can't seem to get the number of matches won correctly. I think the problem has to do with the left join with the matches table.

The idea is to read from the column `result` from the matches table where the results are interpreted as:

```
0 = draw
1 = player1 won
2 = player2 won
```

With the current schema, I can get the number of matches played for each players correctly but not the number of matches played.

I'm also hoping to add the number of tied matches without having to break up into multiple views or tables, if possible. any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you didn't include all of your schema I made some educated guess and came up with this view that I think should work. I included some extra counts for losses and draws as well as I found it easier to verify the result with all results present in the view.

```
CREATE VIEW player_standings AS (
SELECT 
      tournaments.tournament_id as t_id
    , tournaments.tournament_name
    , enroll.player_id
    , players.name
    , COUNT(
       CASE
        WHEN enroll.player_id = matches.player1_id AND matches.result = 1 THEN 1 
        WHEN enroll.player_id = matches.player2_id AND matches.result = 2 THEN 1 
       END) AS wins
    , COUNT(
       CASE
        WHEN enroll.player_id = matches.player1_id AND matches.result = 2 THEN 1 
        WHEN enroll.player_id = matches.player2_id AND matches.result = 1 THEN 1 
       END) AS losses
    , COUNT(CASE WHEN matches.result = 0 THEN 1 END) AS draws
    , COUNT(match_id) AS matches_played

FROM players
INNER JOIN enroll ON enroll.player_id = players.id
INNER JOIN tournaments ON tournaments.tournament_id = enroll.tournament
LEFT JOIN matches ON matches.tournamentid = tournaments.tournament_id 
                 AND enroll.player_id IN (matches.player1_id, matches.player2_id)
GROUP BY 
  tournaments.tournament_id, 
  tournaments.tournament_name, 
  enroll.player_id, 
  players.name
ORDER BY 
  tournaments.tournament_id, 
  wins DESC, 
  matches_played DESC
);
```

Here is the markdown output from the SQL Fiddle I created:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/08eec/1)

**PostgreSQL 9.3 Schema Setup**:

```
create table players (
  id int primary key, 
  name varchar(20)
);

insert into players values 
(1, 'Player 1'),(2, 'Player 2'),
(3, 'Player 3'),(4, 'Player 4'),(5, 'Player 5');

create table tournaments (
  tournament_id int primary key, 
  tournament_name varchar(20)
);

insert into tournaments values (1, 'Tournament 1'),(2, 'Tournament 2');

create table enroll (
  tournament int, 
  player_id int, 
  primary key (tournament, player_id),
  foreign key (tournament) references tournaments(tournament_id),
  foreign key (player_id) references players(id)
);

insert into enroll values 
(1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(1,5),
(2,1),(2,2),(2,3),(2,4),(2,5);

CREATE TABLE matches (
  match_id bigserial PRIMARY KEY, 
  tournamentid INTEGER, 
  player1_id INTEGER, 
  player2_id INTEGER CHECK (player1_id < player2_id), 
  result INTEGER CHECK (result IN (0, 1, 2)),
  FOREIGN KEY(tournamentid, player1_id) REFERENCES enroll(tournament, player_id),
  FOREIGN KEY(tournamentid, player2_id) REFERENCES enroll(tournament, player_id),
  UNIQUE(tournamentid, player1_id, player2_id)
);

insert into matches (tournamentid, player1_id, player2_id, result) values 
 (1, 1, 2, 1) -- 1 win 2 loss
,(1, 1, 3, 1) -- 1 win 3 loss
,(1, 2, 3, 2) -- 2 win 2 loss
,(1, 1, 5, 1) -- 1 win 5 loss

,(2, 2, 4, 0) -- 2 draw 4 draw
,(2, 1, 2, 1) -- 1 win 2 loss
,(2, 3, 4, 2) -- 4 win 3 loss
;

CREATE VIEW player_standings AS (
SELECT 
      tournaments.tournament_id as t_id
    , tournaments.tournament_name
    , enroll.player_id
    , players.name
    , COUNT(
       CASE
        WHEN enroll.player_id = matches.player1_id AND matches.result = 1 THEN 1 
        WHEN enroll.player_id = matches.player2_id AND matches.result = 2 THEN 1 
       END) AS wins
    , COUNT(
       CASE
        WHEN enroll.player_id = matches.player1_id AND matches.result = 2 THEN 1 
        WHEN enroll.player_id = matches.player2_id AND matches.result = 1 THEN 1 
       END) AS losses
    , COUNT(CASE WHEN matches.result = 0 THEN 1 END) AS draws
    , COUNT(match_id) AS matches_played

FROM players
INNER JOIN enroll ON enroll.player_id = players.id
INNER JOIN tournaments ON tournaments.tournament_id = enroll.tournament
LEFT JOIN matches ON matches.tournamentid = tournaments.tournament_id 
                 AND enroll.player_id IN (matches.player1_id, matches.player2_id)
GROUP BY 
  tournaments.tournament_id, 
  tournaments.tournament_name, 
  enroll.player_id, 
  players.name
ORDER BY 
  tournaments.tournament_id, 
  wins DESC, 
  matches_played DESC
);
```

**Query 1**:

```
select * from player_standings
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/08eec/1/0)**:

```
| t_id | tournament_name | player_id |     name | wins | losses | draws | matches_played |
|------|-----------------|-----------|----------|------|--------|-------|----------------|
|    1 |    Tournament 1 |         1 | Player 1 |    3 |      0 |     0 |              3 |
|    1 |    Tournament 1 |         3 | Player 3 |    1 |      1 |     0 |              2 |
|    1 |    Tournament 1 |         2 | Player 2 |    0 |      2 |     0 |              2 |
|    1 |    Tournament 1 |         5 | Player 5 |    0 |      1 |     0 |              1 |
|    1 |    Tournament 1 |         4 | Player 4 |    0 |      0 |     0 |              0 |
|    2 |    Tournament 2 |         4 | Player 4 |    1 |      0 |     1 |              2 |
|    2 |    Tournament 2 |         1 | Player 1 |    1 |      0 |     0 |              1 |
|    2 |    Tournament 2 |         2 | Player 2 |    0 |      1 |     1 |              2 |
|    2 |    Tournament 2 |         3 | Player 3 |    0 |      1 |     0 |              1 |
|    2 |    Tournament 2 |         5 | Player 5 |    0 |      0 |     0 |              0 |
```

Comment: one question if don't mind explaining to me since I m really new to psql.

WHEN enroll.player_id = matches.player1_id AND matches.result = 2 THEN 1

what does the "THEN 1" do exactly? my guess is that it's a counter similar to counter++? correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: @StevenKwok It's not a counter, it's the input to the count function   which counts the number of input rows for which the value of expression is not null. The value doesn't matter, just as long as it's not null. Take a look at this version where I changed count to sum and added a else 0 value for losses, but not winners: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/08eec/2 See the difference?